# How can I put two captions on single picture in Word without being counted as two pictures?

Tags: microsoft-word, caption

When I use Word I would like to to place the title of the picture at the top of it and the source at the bottom of it.

If I use References > Insert Caption, then the figure gets counted twice - first for title and second for the source. I would like it to only be counted once. Is it possible to have two separate captions for one picture, and still only being counted as one picture?

**This is what I want:**

```
Figure 1: Model 1    
PICTURE 1    
Source: My work    
Figure 2: Model 2    
PICTURE 2    
Source: Author (2019)
```

**This is what I have right now:**

```
Figure 1: Model 1
PICTURE 1
Figure 2: Source: My work
Figure 3: Model 2
PICTURE 2
Figure 4: Source: Author (2019)
```

Comment: You should not insert your "source" lines as caption.

Comment: Can you tell me what to use instead of a caption?

Comment: Maybe standard text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of ways.

The first way:

- Insert the image as you have been. Then, after selecting the image,
  insert a caption using "Figure" as the label, and with a position
  above the image.
- Reselect the image and add the second caption with a label of
  "Source" and position of below the image.
- Delete the Sequence field when you add the source attribution on the
  below image caption.

The second way:

- Create a formatted AutoText or AutoCorrect entry of the "Source: "
  character string. The format to use on this text string is the
  Caption paragraph style. (All captions carry a style name of
  "Caption")
- After you have inserted the image and applied the Figure # caption as
  you always do, on the line below the image insert your AutoText or
  AutoCorrect string of "Source: " and type the attribution.

Comment: The first way worked for me. I did not know, that one can delete the sequence field afterwards and that it is then not counted as figure,... in numbering and ToC. So, thanks for that.